# Robot Framework ExcelLibrary: Put Number To Cell

Tags: excel, robotframework

I've been trying to write data into an xls worksheet and save without any luck.
I'm getting the following error: IndexError: list index out of range. Most searches on "Put Number To Cell" yields an answer as "create your own python keyword". Here's my code. It's retrieving and saving the longitude/latitude of an address to the file. Any help appreciated!

```
Open and Read the Excel Record
    # Open the file
    Open Excel  ${EXCEL_FILE_LOCATION}${EXCEL_FILE_NAME}
    # Get the number of rows
    ${iTotalRows} =  Get Row Count  ${PageSheetName}

    # Start the for loop here
    : FOR  ${iRowNum}  IN RANGE  1  ${iTotalRows}+1
    \  ${ADDRESS} =  Read Cell Data By Name  ${PageSheetName}  A${iRowNum}
    \  ${CITY} =  Read Cell Data By Name  ${PageSheetName}  B${iRowNum}
    \  ${STATE} =  Read Cell Data By Name  ${PageSheetName}  C${iRowNum}
    \  ${ZIP} =  Read Cell Data By Name  ${PageSheetName}  D${iRowNum}
    \  ${FINAL_STRING} =  Set Variable  ${ADDRESS} ${CITY} ${STATE} ${ZIP}
    \  ${long}  ${lat}  nasa-site.Enter the Final String into Site  ${FINAL_STRING}
    \  Put Number To Cell  ${PageSheetName}  4  ${iRowNum}  ${long}
    \  Put Number To Cell  ${PageSheetName}  5  ${iRowNum}  ${lat}

    Save Excel  ${EXCEL_FILE_LOCATION}${EXCEL_FILE_NAME}
```

Comment: what happens when you run your code? What does "without any luck" mean? Does it write the wrong data? Does it write the correct data to the wrong place? Does it throw an error? ...?

Comment: I'm getting the following error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: please show the complete error message by clicking the [edit] button and adding it to your question.

Comment: Based upon my research on this, I'd be curious to know if anyone is able to write using "Put Number To Cell" on their local machine. Several people were able to resolve by updating their excel library keywords. Again, any comments/suggestions appreciated.

Here's my env stuff:
  Selenium2Library
  Robot Framework 3.0.2
  Python 2.7.14 on win32

Comment: are you sure that ${lat} ${long} are numbers? Put Number To Cell accepts integers, lat/long may be String or at best,float. Check docs for alternative keywords: http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/ExcelLibrary-KeywordDocumentation.html#Put%20Number%20To%20Cell

Comment: As highlighted by @BryanOakly your question could be refined by creating a [mcve]. Your current example lacks the values for the variables, the actual library used and contains unnecessary lines with respect to your issue. It also helps to be precise and link to sites/questions when referring to them and explain in more detail what you observe.

Comment: `Put Number To Cell` converts internally the argument to float, so the type of the passed arguments shouldn't be the problem - at least, with this exception. Which call causes the exception - could it come from a  `Read Cell Data By Name`? The `xlrd` library this one is based off has some quirks when cells don't "exist", or are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Given the problem is about writing to the file using the keyword: `Put Number To Cell` I've edited out the reading parts of the keyword. The variables were replaced by their corresponding fixed values as this simplifies the example ever further. Even though it's not specified in your code, I'm assuming you're using the `ExcelLibrary` which can is installed using `pip install robotframework-excellibrary`.

The following example reads an excel file and then overwrites the value in the 4th column with the number 3. Then writes the saves the file to a new name as I'm not able to overwrite the open file.

As the keyword is expecting numbers, I'm using the `${4}` and `${3}` to ensure that these are cast to a number and not a string. Not doing so will throw an error.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ExcelLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Open and Read the Excel Record
    Open Excel  ${EXECDIR}\\Book1.xls

    ${iTotalRows} =  Get Row Count  Sheet1

    :FOR  ${iRowNum}  IN RANGE  1  ${iTotalRows}
    \  Put Number To Cell  Sheet1  ${4}  ${iRowNum}  ${3}

    Save Excel  Book2.xls
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried and Tested Solution, python -2.7.x 
Source - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/0gxwAa6f8a4

## Update the below two methods present in file - site-packages\ExcelLibrary\ExcelLibrary.py

**def put_string_to_cell(self, sheetname, column, row, value, check_format = True):**
        """
        Using the sheet name the value of the indicated cell is set to be the string given in the parameter.

```
    Arguments:
            |  Sheet Name (string) | The selected sheet that the cell will be modified from.                                           |
            |  Column (int)        | The column integer value that will be used to modify the cell.                                    |
            |  Row (int)           | The row integer value that will be used to modify the cell.                                       |
            |  Value (string)      | The string value that will be added to the specified sheetname at the specified column and row.   |
    Example:

    | *Keywords*           |  *Parameters*                                                           |
    | Open Excel           |  C:\\Python27\\ExcelRobotTest\\ExcelRobotTest.xls  |     |     |        |
    | Put String To Cell   |  TestSheet1                                        |  0  |  0  |  Hello |

    """
    if self.wb:
        my_sheet_index = self.sheetNames.index(sheetname)
        if self.wb.get_sheet(my_sheet_index).ncols > column and self.wb.get_sheet(my_sheet_index).nrows > row and check_format:
           cell = self.wb.get_sheet(my_sheet_index).cell(int(row), int(column))
           if cell.ctype is XL_CELL_NUMBER:
              self.wb.sheets()
              if not self.tb:
                 self.tb = copy(self.wb)
        else:
          self.wb.sheets()
          if not self.tb:
            self.tb = copy(self.wb)
    if self.tb:
        plain = easyxf('')
        self.tb.get_sheet(my_sheet_index).write(int(row), int(column), value, plain)
```

**def save_excel(self, filename, useTempDir=False):**
        """
        Saves the Excel file indicated by file name, the useTempDir can be set to true if the user needs the file saved in the temporary directory.
        If the boolean useTempDir is set to true, depending on the operating system of the computer running the test the file will be saved in the Temp directory if the operating system is Windows or tmp directory if it is not.

```
    Arguments:
            |  File Name (string)                      | The name of the of the file to be saved.  |
            |  Use Temporary Directory (default=False) | The file will not be saved in a temporary directory by default. To activate and save the file in a temporary directory, pass 'True' in the variable. |
    Example:

    | *Keywords*           |  *Parameters*                                      |
    | Open Excel           |  C:\\Python27\\ExcelRobotTest\\ExcelRobotTest.xls  |
    | Save Excel           |  NewExcelRobotTest.xls                             |

    """
    if useTempDir is True:
        print '*DEBUG* Got fname %s' % filename
        self.tb.save(os.path.join("/", self.tmpDir, filename))
    else:
        if self.wb:
           self.wb.release_resources()
        self.tb.save(filename)
```